# Websocket SSL connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, websocket

I am trying to test a secure websocket but I'm having trouble. Here is my test:

```
var WebSocket = require('ws');

describe('testing Web Socket', function() {
  it('should do stuff', function(done) {
    var ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:15449/', {
      protocolVersion: 8,
      origin: 'https://localhost:15449'
    });
    ws.on('open', function() {
      console.log('open!!!');
      done();
    });
    console.log(ws);
  });
});
```

Here's the log of "ws" after it's created:

```
{ domain: null,
  _events: { open: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  _socket: null,
  _ultron: null,
  _closeReceived: false,
  bytesReceived: 0,
  readyState: 0,
  supports: { binary: true },
  extensions: {},
  _isServer: false,
  url: 'wss://localhost:15449/',
  protocolVersion: 8 }
```

I don't get a log back from open. I am running the project locally and when I use the Chrome Advanced Rest Client tool I am able to connect just fine.

Am I missing something? Please help.

**Edit:** 
I added `ws.on('error')` and it logged out `{ [Error: self signed certificate] code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT' }`
I've also tried following this [code](https://github.com/lukasberns/ws/blob/d8f26c2c7b75ca549dabc03ee6c3802faa9e979a/test/WebSocket.test.js#L1348-L1381) but get the same error.

Comment: Did you check the client's log? It could be that the client refuses to connect with your SSL server due to the certificate being invalid. Review the client's log and update the question.

Comment: `ws` should have an error event.  Maybe log any of those that are occurring?

Comment: Also... I think you defined the onopen event handler _after_ the websocket was already open...

Comment: @AaronDufour I edited the question and now you can see my error says 'self signed certificate'

Comment: Have you already tried https://localhost:15449 in your browser? It should allow you to accept your self-signed certificate in browser.

Comment: @ondrejkosatka I have, there's nothing actually on that page so it says "no data received" and doesn't give me the option

Comment: Have you tried passing `WebSocket` a `rejectUnauthorized: false` option?  It sounds like that might fix the self-signed cert error.

Comment: @AaronDufour yep, that did it! wow, that was super simple i'm not sure how i didn't figure that out.

Comment: Thanks, the solutions helps me!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `https` module is rejecting your self-signed cert (as one would hope).  You can force it to stop checking by passing a `rejectUnauthorized: false` option (which `WebSocket` will pass down to `https`):

```
var ws = new WebSocket('wss://localhost:15449/', {
  protocolVersion: 8,
  origin: 'https://localhost:15449',
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
```

Comment: I tried using this solution for similar issue I am getting with my Cordova Android app. But this gives me an error as   ""Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The subprotocol '[object Object]' is invalid."