# Disable WebSocket certificate validation

Tags: javascript, websocket

I need to disable certificate validation for a WebSocket because I'm using a self-signed certificate.

I found in this question [Websocket SSL connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902547/websocket-ssl-connection) the `rejectUnauthorized` parameter, but that no longer work. In fact, if you go to [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), there are only two parameters: URL and protocol version.

In another question or site (don't remember exactly), I found that if I go first to `https://server_ip`, I would get the prompt about invalid certificate requesting whether I want to proceed or not. Then I could connect using `wss://server_ip` and it would work, and it does, but that's not usable for my case.

So, I need to disable the certificate validation during the creation of the WebSocket. How can I do that?

The code I'm using for testing is the one at https://www.websocket.org/echo.html. I replaced the `websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri);` with `websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri, {rejectUnauthorized: false});` (during testing, also added the `protocolVersion: 8` parameter as in the linked question)

Edit: I need to use self-signed certificates. Let's Encrypt is out of question because it requires a subdomain, and I'd need to manage hundreds to thousands of them then. The application is divided in three parts, that will be deployed to each customer (hundreds of them):

- Management console: using subdomain and a LE certs.
- WebSocket Server 1: need encrypted connection using just the IP
- WebSocket Server 2: need encrypted connection using just the IP

Comment: Are you talking about a one-off on your machine to carry on with your work, or a general way for any visitor to the site?

Comment: @JamesThorpe general way. The client will download a js that will in the background connect to some Python WebSocket servers

Comment: @TheIllusiveMan I know is has been a while, but have you solved it?

Answer (score 3):

I might arrive late here, but as I was having the same issue and no real answer out there, I turned to read the implementation [documentation](https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node/blob/a2cd3065167668a9685db0d5f9c4083e8a1839f0/docs/WebSocketClient.md)

**Methods**

```
connect(requestUrl, requestedProtocols, [[[origin], headers], requestOptions])
```

Will establish a connection to the given *requestUrl*. *requestedProtocols* indicates a list of multiple subprotocols supported by the client. The remote server will select the best subprotocol that it supports and send that back when establishing the connection. origin is an optional field that can be used in user-agent scenarios to identify the page containing any scripting content that caused the connection to be requested. *requestUrl* should be a standard websocket url.

*headers* should be either null or an object specifying additional arbitrary HTTP request headers to send along with the request. This may be used to pass things like access tokens, etc. so that the server can verify authentication/authorization before deciding to accept and open the full WebSocket connection.

**requestOptions** should be either null or an object specifying ***additional configuration options*** to be passed to http.request or https.request. This can be used to pass a custom agent to enable WebSocketClient usage from behind an HTTP or HTTPS proxy server.

*origin* must be specified if you want to pass headers, and both origin and headers must be specified if you want to pass *requestOptions*. The origin and headers parameters may be passed as null.

Hence, as the documentation stated, unless you have specific configuration for any of these parameters you should pass null. That solved the maze. It came to be:

```js
var client = new WebSocket();
client.connect(WSSrvUrl, null, null, null, {rejectUnauthorized: false});
//or depending on the implementation you're using (this applies to Nodejs and web browser implementation:
var client = new WebSocket(WSSrvUrl, null, null, null, {rejectUnauthorized: false});
```

And that's it.

SDG

Comment: I don't see such a constructor in docs https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebSocket
And it does not work for me. Is it applicable for NodeJS only?

Comment: indeed mate, as you see in the documentation I cited above. If you're looking for browser WS clients, it is actually easier since the browser itself gives you graphically the way to continue to the website despite the SSL/TLS certificate being "insecure" meaning self-signed

Comment: I am afraid that proceeding to an insecure website, hitting extra buttons, reading a ton of text there that state that it is not safe and finally reaching the page is absolutely not user friendly and we can't sell it to clients

Comment: well mate, if you're intending to commercialize/sell your development/code you shall drop some money buying a proper set of HTTPS certificates from a well known signer company ;)

Comment: @Andrew Not everything in software development is all or nothing. In my case I need a connection on prem between 2 devices through an external cloud service. Since both devices are on same site, they will be aware if they are conected or not. Still, I'd like to have the outbound cloud connection to be secured. I should be able to do that without dropping some money with a proper set of certificates.

Comment: @YoavMoran everything on this world is situational. As a result, for your specific situation you might need to look out there for some org who can provide you for trusted certificates out of grace or at a lower price... However, in practice if you are intending to publish/work with selfsigned certificates you will get the "insecure" flag even thought you may be working in a LAN or MAN. That's the IETF's standard