# How to connect from browser JS to websocket server with self-signed SSL certificate?

Tags: javascript, http, ssl, websocket

I have an app running behind web server. Initially user loads a page via http (not https, because my http server is running on router and I need to avoid certificate warnings), then when page is loaded a websocket connection is open (wss) to the app that provides data for the web page.

- It works fine, if no SSL used - http (no SSL) server + ws (no SSL) websocket.
- It works fine, if I use public domain name (just for testing, not on router) with SSL (https) + wss (SSL) websocket.
- But it does not work (both on local domain name or public) if SSL certificate is self-signed for websocket (not matter, http or https is used).

Tested with 2048 and 4096 bits keys.

The following code is used to connect:

```
    try {
        // var socket = new WebSocket(this.url); // This does not work, I believe because of self-signed certificate is rejected
        var socket = new WebSocket(this.url, {
            // protocolVersion: 8, // Tried but no difference
            // origin: 'https://myserver.com:443', // Tried but no difference
            rejectUnauthorized: false // This line produces an error below
        })
        socket.onclose = function(event) {
            console.log("closed:", event.code, event.reason); // code is `1006`
        })

        socket.onerror = function(error) {
            console.log("error:", error); // Nothing useful in this error object
        })

        socket.onmessage = function(event) {
            console.log("data:", event.data);
        })
    } catch(e) {
        this.error("connect error reason: " + e) // Is never called
    }
```

Firefox error:

```
error: connect error reason: SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified
```

Chrome error:

```
error: connect error reason: SyntaxError: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The subprotocol '[object Object]' is invalid.
```

I am able to connect to wss server using wscat (with `-n` option to ignore self-signed certificate error):

```
wscat -n -c wss://myserver.com:8443
```

How do I connect from browser JS to SSL websocket server with self-signed certificate?

P.S. Please keep in mind, that I will use plain http to load the web page.

**UPDATE**: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38242334/disable-websocket-certificate-validation) question with answer that states that parameters must be passed differently to websocket costructor:

```
var socket = new WebSocket(this.url, null, null, null, {rejectUnauthorized: false});
```

But I don't see this constructor in [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).

Though, I tried the fix and if http is used, I still get `1006` error in Chrome, but I get `1015` (TLS handshake reserved).
When using the same self-signed SSL certificate for https server and try to load the page, I get `1006` error both in Chrome and Firefox.