# syntax error after using wss javascript

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket

i was implement my websocket ssl using javascript ..
and here is my javascript :

```
ws = new WebSocket($F("uri"), {
      protocolVersion: 8,
      origin: 'https://localhost:9003',
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    });
```

but i have an error in my script

> SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified

[here is my screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDLYX.png)

Comment: remove your first opening bracket.

Comment: sorry it's my fault ..

Comment: i was edite my question

Comment: i was follow this script on this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30902547/websocket-ssl-connection

but it's same error ..

Comment: does the $F("uri") is defined ? it must be the url of your websocket.

Comment: it's was defined ..
it's for form input on my web ..

Comment: $F('uri') it's just id for input form