# Is it possible to communicate ionic android app and esp32 via Websocket with SSL? If yes, then how?

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, websocket, esp32, ionic-native

I have hosted websocket with ssl server on esp32 and ionic android app is my client. It works properly in computer, but it fails in android.
This is my client code.

```
const socket = new WebSocket("wss://server_ip:443/chat");

  socket.onopen = function (e) {
    console.log("[open] Connection established");
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log("Sending to server");
      socket.send("HELLO");
    }, 5000);
  };

  socket.onmessage = function (event: any) {
    console.log(`[message] Data received from server: ${event.data}`);
  };

  socket.onclose = function (event: any) {
    if (event.wasClean) {
      console.log(
        `[close] Connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code} reason=${event.reason}`
      );
    } else {
      console.log("[close] Connection died");
    }
  };

  socket.onerror = function (error: any) {
    console.log(`[error] ${error}`);
  };
```

Error: WebSocket connection to 'wss://server_ip:443/chat' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled

Comment: your esp32 is using self signed certificate and you probably forced your browser to ignore such "inconvience" to get it work. [you can probably instruct websocket in android to ignore it as well although it is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30921980/12396017). Also you can probably do it at higher level , like ```cordova.plugins.certificates.trustUnsecureCerts(true)``` but it is much worse from security point of view because other ssl connection would be affected as well.If it works write it down here as an answer to this question so future seekers would benefit from your experiense

Comment: your question is a good one and people could benefit from your experiences. If you manage to solve it then please share your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: did you find any sulotion?