# how to disable hostname verification Ionic/Angular webSocket

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, websocket, webview

I want to open a tls websocket from my Ionic application to an android server in local network with an ip that is not fixed (which I'm getting using mdsn in android) and I am using rxjs websocket to do this. when I try to connect to a tls websocket with `wss://` protocol, it fails in handshake, and I'm convinced it is because my client is trying to verify the hostname (and obviously fail). Is there a way to cancel this default behavior of rxjs websocket? or any other way to do this without handling the whole websocket inside native?

I have tried adding `rejectUnauthorized: false` to the websocket options as a sulotion, but it didn't work (also I have noticed there is no `rejectUnauthorized` key in `WebSocketSubjectConfig`).

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67395836/is-it-possible-to-communicate-ionic-android-app-and-esp32-via-websocket-with-ssl) could've been related to my problem, but had no answer yet.

I thought it might not be possible to change this behavior for a PWA app because of browser's restrictions. If that's true, is there a way to do it inside native app by somehow changing the `webView` that is being used?

I am using:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 6.20.8
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.5.1
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 14.2.10
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 14.2.6
   @angular/cli                  : 14.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 4.6.3
   @capacitor/android : 4.6.3
   @capacitor/core    : 4.6.3
```